# Iterating a string and replacing an element in python

Tags: python, string, replace, indexing

I am attempting to search through two strings looking for matching elements. If the strings have two elements in common that are in different positions, I want to make that element in the 'guess' string a COW. If the strings have two elements in the same position, the element is a BULL.

Here is what I have:

```
        if index(number,i) in guess and not index(guess,i) == index(guess,i):
            replace(index(guess,i),'COW')

        if index(guess,i) == index(number,i):
            replace(index(guess,i),'BULL')
```

I'm not sure if I'm using index correctly.

Comment: `index()` and `replace()` are methods *on* the string, not functions.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by string elements.

Comment: Giving examples of your input strings would help, presumably it's like "I have a house in red" and "what house is that" where "house" would be mangled.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you need to be using `index()` and `replace()` as string methods, like Martijn said in a comment.

This would be like so: `guess.index(i)` to find the index of `i` in the string `guess`.

You might want to check out [find()](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=index#str.find) which will do the same as `index()` but won't raise an exception when the substring is not found.

Also note that you are seeing if the result of `index()` is in the string `guess`.  That is an error, since an integer cannot be in a string!  `index()` returns an integer!

Then consider that you are stating `... and not guess.index(i) == guess.index(i):` (I fixed the `index` code) which makes no sense, since of course they are equal! They are the same thing!

Lastly, you are using `replace` incorrectly.
From [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=index#str.replace), `replace` takes a string as the first argument - not an index!  Try using it like so: `guess = guess.replace(i, 'BULL')`. That will change `guess` to have *all* occurrences of `i` replaced by the string `'BULL'`.

I wasn't concerned with you actual algorithm here, but just your basic errors.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use the `index()` method. Instead, I would turn the string's elements into a list, then say:

```
listOne = [hello,goodbye,adios, shalom]
listTwo = [hello,adios,arrivaderci]

def cowbull(L1, L2):
    for i in range(len(L1)):
        if L1[i] in L2:
            if L1[i] == L2[i]:
                L1[i] = 'BULL'
                L2[i] = 'BULL'
            else:
                L1[i] = 'COW'
                L2[L1[i]] = 'COW'
```

This is just how I would do it, but using the way you and William's code may work well also. I am just used to doing it this way, and it may very well be not as efficient as his, but it usually works very well.